# How to request real data through Web Api

Tags: c#, rest

I want to see how can I get real data from a WebApi. All I see online is something like this :

```
 // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
        {
            CustomerContext customersdb = new CustomerContext();
            return customersdb.Customers;
        }
```

I actually want to make a GET request to facebook api for example and pull data from there. How do I write the GET method?

Comment: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/ , you don't need to make raw requests use the .Net library they provide.

Comment: I just took facebook as an example. I don't need anything complicated with access token . I just need to do a simple GET request to a real website for data. How should I do that

Comment: google for web api sandbox and you will get a lot of real web api's to test against. Google APIs would be a good place to start since they wont mind the load that you would put on them

Comment: try this https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using

Comment: @Besa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415709/how-to-use-verb-get-with-webclient-request , simply using the `HttpWebRequest` class the is available in `System.Net`

Comment: The Web API here is what *you* provide. Fetching data from someone else's web API has nothing to do with this. :)

Comment: Just add a reference to the external web service in your Web API project, query it and return the data in your GET method.

Answer (score 2):

MS WebApi is used primarily to build [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) services (the server side), and you seem to be asking about consuming them (the client side).

---

When you want to retrieve data from it, you are acting as an HTTP client -- and it does not matter that the server is built with WebApi or any other language/framework: in fact that is partly the point of doing things over HTTP (and REST).

All that matters from a client perspective is what is returned. These days, most APIs return JSON data, though some use XML or support multiple data types.

For a .NET web client, you can use [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get raw data, or one of many [smart REST client libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rest+client) that let you immediately use retrieved results by deserializing them into a typed object.

For example, [from an answer by @wonea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172209/7913) using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

```
var client = new RestClient("192.168.0.1");
var request = new RestRequest("api/item/", Method.GET);
var queryResult = client.Execute<List<Items>>(request).Data;
```